# TypeError about number of arguments shuffling deck of cards

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that:

1. a function that creates a deck of cards
2. a function that randomly changes the order of cards in the deck.
3. a function that removes the first card_count cards from the deck and returns them as a list.

Things worked fine for the first function, but for the latter 2 functions, both gave me an error message like `TypeError: deal_card() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Could you please take a look at my program and note what's wrong?

The correct result for the latter two functions should be:

```
>>deck2.shuffle_deck()
>>[A of ♠, 10 of ♠, 3 of ♠, 7 of ♠, 5 of ♠, 4 of ♠, 8 of ♠, J of ♠, 9 of ♠, Q of ♠,
   6 of ♠, 2 of ♠, K of ♠]

>>deck2.deal_card(7)
>>>[A of ♠, 10 of ♠, 3 of ♠, 7 of ♠, 5 of ♠, 4 of ♠, 8 of ♠]
```

My code:

```
import random
from random import shuffle


class RankError(Error):
    pass
class SuitError(Error):
    pass
class NoCardsError(Error):
    pass

all_rank = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
all_suit = ["♠", "♥", "♦", "♣"]
hand = []

class PlayingCard:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        if str(rank) not in all_rank:
            raise RankError("Invalid rank!")
        if suit not in all_suit:
            raise SuitError("Invalid suit!")
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + " of " + self.suit

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%r of %r" % (self.rank, self.suit)


class Deck:
    def __init__(self, suit = all_suit):
        self.cards = [PlayingCard(rank, one_suit) for rank in all_rank
                                                    for one_suit in suit]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%r of %r" % (self.rank, self.suit)

    def shuffle_deck():
        self.shuffled_cards = random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal_card(card_count):
        if card_count > len(cards):
            raise NoCardsError("Cannot deal 7 cards. The deck only has 6 cards left!")
        else:
            hand = hand.append(cards.pop())
            return hand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `self` in a few places:

```
def shuffle_deck(self):  # here
    self.shuffled_cards = random.shuffle(self.cards)

def deal_card(self, card_count):  # here
    if card_count > len(self.cards):  # here
        raise NoCardsError("Cannot deal 7 cards. The deck only has 6 cards left!")
    else:
        hand = hand.append(self.cards.pop())  # here
        return hand
```

There could be other errors, but the missing `self` on `deal_card` is what's  causing the exception.